# Optimize images on production server

Tags: linux, css, web-services, magento, gulp

Is there any way to Optimize all product images under media folder directly on production server.

I was thinking to do by Gulp or Grunt but both required lots of installation on server which I think would not be the best workaround.

Is there any better solution you guys can suggest me?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: I thought Magento automatically resized images to the size needed. Although not optimising completely, it does mean you don't serve large images when only a thumbnail, say, is needed.

Answer (score 1):

It's fairly trivial to run a linux command to compress/optimize image sizes if this is what you're looking to do.  This article explains it: http://ask.xmodulo.com/compress-jpeg-images-command-line-linux.html and their are equivalents for png's or other image types if you google for them.

To compress all images in a folder and output to a separate folder called 'compressed'. On debian based os, it would basically go as:

```
sudo apt-get install jpegoptim
find . -name "*.jpg" | xargs jpegoptim -d ./compressed -p
```